# Logstash & Elasticsearch: Unwanted indexes being added

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, cluster-computing, logstash, kibana

I haven't worked on my Elasticsearch + Kibana project in a while, but when I go on my elasticsearch-head frontend now, I notice the addition of multiple indexes (image below)

[image: Elasticsearch-head frontend]

If I scroll to the right, I see my Logstash related files, such as `logstash-2015.06.26`. So everything seems to be normal besides the fact that these elements appear (they are also numerous)

Surely I must have done something wrong for this to happen, it seems as if Logstash is parsing all the files of an unwanted directory. I cannot find anything unusual in my `input` or `filter` files.

Any ideas on how to figure this out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were scanned by a vulnerability scanner.  Since you had no security on your cluster, a vulnerability scanner tried to do a POST to some URLs on your port 9200 which caused indexes to be created.

Comment: Okay thank you this makes sense! Is there anything I can do except requesting that the vulnerability scanner excludes my `kibana` directory? In my current situation, someone else would be in charge of this. Would setting up the `shield.transport.filter` help, for example?

Comment: If your only access to the cluster is going to be from kibana/other things on the same machine, you can configure elasticsearch to only listen on localhost.  The other possibility is to use a firewall (on the machine or external to the machine) that restricts access to port 9200 to only allowed machines (preventing the intrusion scanner from hitting it).

Comment: Actually, I need several machines on the same network to access these Kibana dashboards and I am not able to access the firewall's settings myself. I am wondering if there is a way to prevent this scan from happening from the ELK stack itself.

Comment: There is if you pay for a support contract. You can install shield then.